# K means clustering or sorting the data

Tags: database, k-means

I have a large database which contains data  about the countries like country name,position, HDI(Human development index) and population. I need to classify this data in to some "K" number of groups based upon the population. One of my friend suggested that in this case K-means clustring will be useful. But I am thinking, this can be done directly by sorting the data according to population and then divide this sorted data in to groups. Are there some difference between these two approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively splitting along one dimension results in a decision tree. It is a different data structure. All the cuts between the groups are along axis (horizontally or vertically). K-means can achieve a balance because the cuts are not necessarily horizontally or vertically (most of the time they aren't).

Actually, the decision tree approach is also very useful. You might well try it.